# Is it safe to wrap an entire CFM page in a cfoutput tag

Tags: coldfusion

I am placing a `<cfoutput>` tag around my entire `<html>` tag. The ColdBox best practice guide states *"When you are creating view templates, try to always surround it with 1 cfoutput tag, instead of nesting them all over the place."*

But I have on occasion seen errors pop up where a `<script>` block containing javascript code is within the `<cfoutput>` tag. This probably because Coldfusion sees a hash `#` and tries to parse it but it can't because its javascript.

So how does one get away with having a single `<cfoutput>` tag on a view page in which to place everything?

Comment: I can see where this might solve some problems, but I think it would create more than it would solve. I use `<cfoutput group="xxx">` way too much for this to be a viable approach.

Comment: Also, do you have a link to where they recommend this. I would like to hear their thinking

Comment: I found this on http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/DevelopmentBestPractices.cfm

Comment: @JamesAMohler that's the correct link. it comes under the section titled "General ColdFusion Best Practices & Conventions"

Comment: The opinion expressed in @JamesAMohler's link contradicts advice I was once given in a presentation by Ben Forta.  However, that presentation was quite some time ago when the most recent cf version was 6 or 7.

Comment: I cannot recall being told one way or another is 'better'. If you are worried about performance, I would hazard a guess the performance difference would be barely measurable.

Comment: @JamesAMohler you said you use `<cfoutput group="xxx">`. You can use `<cfloop group="xxx">` instead

Comment: @volumeone that is a 'relatively' new feature - maybe since Cf 10.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any significant security or performance concerns in regards to wrapping an entire page in cfoutput.  Of course, you'll always need to be aware to escape any pound signs by doubling them up any time you're inside a cfoutput.

The best practices in that ColdBox guide are geared primarily toward readability and reducing clutter on the page.  If you have large sections of the page that you don't want to escape pound signs on or if you like to use cfoutput's grouping functionality, there's nothing wrong with breaking up your cfoutputs in a way that makes sense.

In the olden days of CF there might have been more overhead, but these days I can't imagine it being more than a few nanoseconds, and that's once at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In my view files I tend to wrap all output in a single `cfoutput` tag.

You can escape `#` symbols in JavaScript, etc, by converting them to `##`.

Comment: But if you're importing in massive javascript libraries in your `<head>` area then its not practical to escape all hashes right?

Comment: Right so you need to be selective where you are nesting your `<cfoutput>`.  Be pragmatic.

Comment: If by 'importing' you mean using the `<script>` tag, you need not worry about escaping `#` in those libraries - they will be loaded by the browser after ColdFusion is done processing. If by 'importing' you mean using `cfinclude` to actually put the JS in the page (rather than using `<script>`) that is a bad idea...don't do that.

Comment: I took a jQuery tutorial a couple of years ago.  The advice given in that book was to write all your javascript, including library imports, after your closing html tag, not in the head section as I was originally taught.

Comment: I don't keep my scripts in the head section either. I load them at the very end just before the closing body tag. but wherever they are, if they are contained within a <cfoutput> block then i think it can cause some issues. Escaping each hash in javascript is not practical I think.

Comment: @ScottStroz I have various tracking codes placed in <script> tags at the bottom of my page before the closing </cfoutput> tag. Are you sure Coldfusion doesn't attempt to parse this?

Comment: If you are using `<script>` tag to load an external script, no the linked file will not be parsed by CF - it is loaded by the browser. But if you have raw JS code in the `<script>` block, then any `#` in there will cause issues - simply escape them as Simon noted. Or, simply move the closing `cfoutput` tag above these `<script>` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question as posted is yes.

There are only two issues that I'm aware of to keep in mind:

1. Escape any single hashtags (#) with double hashtags (##) that may occur in your code (i.e., CSS, JS, etc.) ... unless the hashtags are actually being wrapped around a CFML function or variable.
2. If you're using "cfoutput query...", you will probably want to close the first "cfoutput" tag, and then reopen after the query output. Otherwise, you can run into issues when trying to group query output.

My preference is to use as few  tags as possible, mostly for readability and to reduce clutter.